# Particle System change rendering display for unknown reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have prefab in which has these components attached to it: Transform, Particle System and Spell(Script). So that is whole prefab. I called it when player come close to object with this attached to the 'object':

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if(col.tag == "Player")
    {               
        GameObject test;
        GetComponent<CastSpell>().castSpell(100000.0f, out test);
        test.transform.LookAt(col.transform);
    }
}
```

So it creates spell at perfect position (object/monster position) so it look like that monster is doing it. `100000.0f` is number of seconds it stays there before destroyed and it should be something like `0.5f` or less but for test purpose i set it long. So problem is when i am watching that particle system it is ok, but when i start moving particle system start changing, i guess, rotation (but in inspector nothing is changing). So here is the image of how it looks:

Particle system in next images is zoomed and a lot bigger so you can see what is happening:

When i stay it looks like this:
[image: Idle]

When i go backwards:
[image: Back]

To the right:
[image: Right]

Forward:
[image: Forward]

I think there is not anything else that is connected to particle system so i guess it is something about setting it up but as much as i try i couldn't find what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to set Particle System/Renderer/Camera Scale to 0. I couldn't find exact documentation for it.